# I need software that can help me create videos like this

Tags: video-editing

I need software that can help me create videos like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVezYxFEH5Q
It should be cost-free and run on GNU/Linux. Also, I am very interested in dynamic zooms and transitions while the video is ongoingas you can see in the video.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: On what OS must it run, how much may it cost, what features do you need. Links are good for reference, but bad if they are the only source of information. Questions (and answers) should be self-contained ;)

Comment: @Izzy thanks for the suggestions :) I have amended the question. Also added bounty on the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: dear @Community If by reading this question you are having a hard time - then maybe just read harder? It is all clear there. I need software suggestions for video-making software with dynamic zooms and transitions.

Comment: Community is a bot, used to add anonymous boiler-plate comments from QA reviews, since recent stack-wide changes to the review structure. It's a bit of a blunt instrument & personally I think this particular boiler-plate is about as useful as a chocolate fireplace.

Comment: yes - it almost works an described here https://pics.me.me/so-bob-why-should-we-hire-you-thats-a-stupid-47771110.png :D

Comment: Sorry. I liked both answers but only could give the bounty to one and grant answer to other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The features you are requesting are common to almost all video editors... One known exception being avidemux (it is made for much simpler workflows).

For you request I suggest **kdenlive** ([kdenlive site click here](https://kdenlive.org/en/)). It comes with almost all major distros and it is easy to start working with! Also great tutorials and examples on youtube and other sites, so worth a try...

Answer (score 1):

### [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/)

**Freeware.**
Multi-platform, Mac, Win, nix.
Unless you need to integrate actual vision mixing hardware, there's nothing to touch it for free.
It's easily a match for Final Cut Pro & Premier.

…and, did I mention…  it's free !!

The only downside is it really is jumping right in at the deep end. Expect it to take between two & six months to be truly comfortable with it.

[No affiliation]